# Render an array element in a react component

Tags: reactjs

I cant seem to render the dropdown items.Not sure I have the syntax right, but the log shows

```
{menu: Array(5)}
menu: (5) ['Guitar', 'Ams Work', 'Learning', 'Food', 'Exercise']
```

Heres the relevent code.

```
const data = ["Guitar", "Ams Work","Learning","Food","Exercise"]
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header />
    <ToggleVisibility basicexample={<MyDropdown menu = {data}/>} /> 
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

....

```
function MyDropdown(menu) {
  console.log(menu)
  return (
    
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
        Dropdown Button
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu >
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">{menu[0]}</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">{menu[1]}</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">{menu[2]}</Dropdown.Item>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}
```

Comment: The first parameter of a function component is the `props` object, so maybe you want to call `props.menu` instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only argument given to a function component is the props, which is an object. You could destructure it to access the `menu` prop.

Then, use `Array#map` to render a `Dropdown.Item` for each element of the array.

```js
function MyDropdown({ menu }) {
  return (
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
        Dropdown Button
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu>
        {menu.map((m, i) => <Dropdown.Item href={"#/action-" + i}>{m}</Dropdown.Item>)}
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}
```

Comment: misuse of `Array#map`, children need a `key` property

Comment: @Mulan Not adding a `key` isn't related to misusing `map` (as opposed to, for example, using `map` to loop instead of `forEach`). Passing the index as the key is also the same as not passing it at all.

Comment: And renaming it to `key` is just confusing. It gives the OP a false sense of security when it is in fact the index..

Answer (score -1):

Change `menu` -

```js
function MyDropdown(menu) {
  return …
}
```

To `props` -

```js
function MyDropdown(props) {
  return …
}
```

The menu is accessible via `props.menu` -

```
function MyDropdown(props) {
  return (
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
        Dropdown Button
      </Dropdown.Toggle>
      <Dropdown.Menu>
        {props.menu.map((item, key) =>
          <Dropdown.Item
            key={key}
            href={`#/action-${key}`}
            children={item}
          />
        )}
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}
```

TypeScript -

```
function MyDropdown(props: {
  menu: Array<string>
}) {
  return …
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why you are going to pass that array by props ? It's prop drilling.
Every component should be isolated, and independent.

Anyway. `menu` prop should be destructured, because it's not an argument of function but properties of a component.

```
❌ function MyDropdown(menu)

✅ function MyDropdown({ menu })
```

Finally. You can use template string also like below (`index`). Remember to don't miss a `key` prop for a `map` method.

```
function MyDropdown({ menu }: { menu: string[] }) {

  const items = menu.map((item, index) => (
    <Dropdown.Item key={item} href={`#/action-${index}`}>{item}</Dropdown.Item>
  ))

  return (
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
        Dropdown Button
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu>{items}</Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  )
}
```

Bonus tip. Every `prop` should be typed as `camelCase`

```
❌ <ToggleVisibility basicexample={<MyDropdown menu={data}/>} />

✅ <ToggleVisibility basicExample={<MyDropdown menu={data}/>} />
```